# XML Notepad++ - A name contained an invalid character, Error Parsing "x" as NCName datatype

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am a completely new user when it comes to any type of coding, so forgive me in advance for any misuse of terminology, I will provide any information needed.

I am trying to validate my XML file with an XSD schema in Notepad++. When validating, I get the error on the 1st line, saying: "A name contained an invalid character. Error parsing 'Movie Data' as NCName Datatype. Googling this error led me to see that there can not be any white spaces when validating, however, I have no "white spaces" in my code, which you will see below. I am at a complete loss on why it is saying it cannot parse this attribute, as its not even something thats in my code. My xsd code can also be found below the xml.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Movie_Info xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sfuchs2_Movies.xsd">
    <Movie_Data ENTRY="NEW">
        <Movie_Name>Colossus: The Forbin Project</Movie_Name>
        <Movie_ID>01</Movie_ID>
        <Movie_Title>Colossus: The Forbin Project</Movie_Title>
        <Movie_Genre>Science Fiction</Movie_Genre>
        <Movie_Year_Released>1970</Movie_Year_Released>
        <Movie_Director>Joseph Sargent</Movie_Director>
        <Synopsis>Thinking this will prevent war,

                  the US government gives an impenetrable supercomputer

                  total control over launching nuclear missiles.

                  But what the computer does with the power is

                  unimaginable to its creators.</Synopsis>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>1</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Braeden</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Eric</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>01</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>2</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Clarck</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Susan</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>01</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>3</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Pinset</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Gordon</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>01</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>1</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Bridges</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>James</First_Name>
            <Union>NWGA</Union>
            <Movie_Id_Association>1</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>2</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Jones</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>D.F.</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>1</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Rating>9.4</Rating>
        <Recommended>true</Recommended>
        <Submitted_By>Max Magguilli</Submitted_By>
    </Movie_Data>
    <Movie_Data ENTRY="NEW">
        <Movie_Name>Fantastic Voyage</Movie_Name>
        <Movie_ID>02</Movie_ID>
        <Movie_Title>Fantastic Voyage</Movie_Title>
        <Movie_Genre>Science Fiction</Movie_Genre>
        <Movie_Year_Released>1966</Movie_Year_Released>
        <Movie_Director>Richard Fleischer</Movie_Director>
        <Synopsis>A scientist is nearly assassinated. 
                 
                 In order to save him, a submarine is shrunken to microscopic 
                 
                 size and injected into his bloodstream with a small crew. 
                 
                 Problems arise almost as soon as they enter it.</Synopsis>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>1</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Boyd</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Stephen</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>02</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>2</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Welch</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Raquel</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>02</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>3</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>O'Connell</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Arthur</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>02</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>1</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Kleiner</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Harry</First_Name>
            <Union>SWGA</Union>
            <Movie_Id_Association>2</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>2</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Duncan</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>David</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>2</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Rating>9.65</Rating>
        <Recommended>true</Recommended>
        <Submitted_By>Nancy Zima</Submitted_By>
    </Movie_Data>
    <Movie_Data ENTRY="NEW">
        <Movie_Name>The Godfather "Part 1"</Movie_Name>
        <Movie_ID>03</Movie_ID>
        <Movie_Title>The Godfather "Part 1"</Movie_Title>
        <Movie_Genre>Crime Drama</Movie_Genre>
        <Movie_Year_Released>1972</Movie_Year_Released>
        <Movie_Director>Francis Ford Coppola</Movie_Director>
        <Synopsis> The aging patriarch of an organized crime 
                
                dynasty in postwar New York City transfers 
                
                control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant 
                
                youngest son.</Synopsis>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>1</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Brando</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Marlon</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>03</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>2</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Pacino</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Al</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>03</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>3</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Caan</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>James</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>03</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>1</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Puzo</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Mario</First_Name>
            <Union>NWGA</Union>
            <Movie_Id_Association>3</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Rating>9</Rating>
        <Recommended>true</Recommended>
        <Submitted_By>Max Magguilli</Submitted_By>
    </Movie_Data>
    <Movie_Data ENTRY="NEW">
        <Movie_Name>The Batman</Movie_Name>
        <Movie_ID>04</Movie_ID>
        <Movie_Title>The Batman</Movie_Title>
        <Movie_Genre>Superhero</Movie_Genre>
        <Movie_Year_Released>2022</Movie_Year_Released>
        <Movie_Director>Matt Reeves</Movie_Director>
        <Synopsis>Batman ventures into Gotham City's underworld when a sadistic killer leaves behind a trail of cryptic clues. 
            
            As the evidence begins to lead closer to home and the scale of the perpetrator's plans become clear,
             
             he must forge new relationships, unmask the culprit and bring justice to the abuse of power and corruption
             
             that has long plagued the metropolis.</Synopsis>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>1</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Pattinson</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Robert</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>04</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>2</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Kravitz</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Zoe</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>04</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Movie_Stars>
            <Movie_Star_ID>3</Movie_Star_ID>
            <Last_Name>Dano</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Paul</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>04</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Movie_Stars>
        <Writers>
            <Writer_ID>1</Writer_ID>
            <Last_Name>Reeves</Last_Name>
            <First_Name>Matt</First_Name>
            <Movie_Id_Association>4</Movie_Id_Association>
        </Writers>
        <Rating>9</Rating>
        <Recommended>true</Recommended>
        <Submitted_By>Samuel Fuchs</Submitted_By>
    </Movie_Data>
</Movie_Info>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsd:element name="Movie_Info">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Movie_Data"
                             minOccurs="0"
                             maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Name"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_ID"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Title"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Genre"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Year_Released"
                                         type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Director"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Synopsis"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Movie_Stars"
                                         minOccurs="1"
                                         maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Movie_Star_ID"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Last_Name"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="First_Name"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Movie_ID_Association"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="Writers"
                                         minOccurs="1"
                                         maxOccurs="5">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Writer_ID"
                                                     type="xsd:integer"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Last_Name"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="First_Name"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Union"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="Movie_ID_Association"
                                                     type="xsd:string"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="Rating"
                                         type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Recommended"
                                         type="xsd:boolean"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Submitted_By"
                                         type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Minimal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TVShow_Info xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sfuchs2_Movies.xsd">
    <TVShow_Data ENTRY="NEW">
        
    </TVShow_Data>
</TVShow_Info>
```

Comment: Did not see anything either. You might start to remove/add XML parts in the file till you located the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following are all different names.  Fix these discrepancies to address your present error:

- Your XML has elements named, `MovieData`.
- Your XSD defines elements named, `Movie_Data`.
- Your error message complains about an element named, `Movie Data`.

(Whether you re-typed the error message wrong or messed-up in some other way is unclear, but there's clearly a degree of naming carelessness going on that must be addressed.)

Comment: Hi, I changed the elements so they line up in both files as Movie_Data, validating again provided the same response. I am positive that the error message says 'Movie Data' (not Movie_Data or MovieData), which is weird because that isn't even an element in my code anymore. I would provide a screenshot but can't seem to be able to in a comment.

Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: Update your question with your corrected XML and XSD, ***and*** reduce your problem to the *minimal* [mcve] that exhibits the issue if you'd like us to investigate further.

Comment: Hi, I replaced the code with its updated version, I also included a minimal reproductible example with different elements, which produces the same error (Error Parsing 'Movie Data' as NCName datatype) I can see that my formatting is a little janky at the end but ill try to fix it up, I would be happy to provide any more info you need.

Comment: Sorry, but there remain a slew additional basic mistakes unrelated to your reported error, and your reported error makes no sense given what you've posted, and what you've posted is nowhere near a ***minimal*** [mcve], despite my request.  Moving on.  Good luck.

Comment: My guess, and it's a pretty wild guess, is that the schema you've shown us isn't the schema that's actually being picked up in your validation run. I say that partly because the error message refers to something that isn't in the files you've shown us, and also because it's such a common beginner's mistake to get muddled between different versions of the same file.